# Get first object in the JSONObject using int variable

Tags: android, json, api, parsing, key

I need to get the string in `extract` object. but the JSON object contains some random variable, so when I call through `JSONObject pg = qr.getJSONObject(0)` I get an error stating I can't use an integer.

Here is the jsonobject:

```
{"query":
    {"pages":
        {"7529378":
            {"pageid":7529378,
             "ns":0,
             "title":"Facebook",
             "extract":"<p><b>Facebook</b> is an online social networking service.</p>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following Key structure but failed.

```
Iterator<?> keys = pg.keys(); 
while( keys.hasNext() ){
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    if( pg.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ){
        // get all values from JSONObject
        str=pg.optString("extract"); 

    //get  ns, title, extract,.. in same way from jObjpages 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826520/json-object-getting-the-key-and-the-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826520/json-object-getting-the-key-and-the-value)

Answer (score -2):

Do something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JsonObject(your_main_string);
JSONObject query= json.getJsonObject("query");
JSONObject pages = query.getJsonObject("pages");
JSONObject id= pages .getJsonObject("7529378");
String extract = id.getString("extract");
```

Comment: Probably 7529378 is the random value... So he can't put it as hard-coded