# Json Object - Getting the Key and the Value

Tags: java, javascript, android, json

I am a newbie to JSON . So If this is a very basic doubt don't scold me . I have a JSON Object Reference and I want to get the Key(Object has only one Key Value Pair) . How do I get it in Java ?

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306271/create-key-value-pairs-string-in-json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `jsonObject.keys()` for getting all keys. Then you may iterate over keys to get the first key out of them like :

```
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
if( keys.hasNext() ){
   String key = (String)keys.next(); // First key in your json object
}
```

Comment: its better do it in while :  while (keys.hasNext()) { String key = keys.next(); ...}

Answer (score 1):

`json.keys()` will give all the keys in your `JSONObject` where `json` is an object of `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

Recursively search for a key, and if found, return its value

```
    String recurseKeys(JSONObject jObj, String findKey) throws JSONException {

    Iterator<?> keys = jObj.keys();
    String key = "";

    while (keys.hasNext() && !key.equalsIgnoreCase(findKey)) {
        key = (String) keys.next();

        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(findKey)) {
            return jObj.getString(key);
        }
        if (jObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            return recurseKeys((JSONObject)jObj.get(key), findKey);
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Usage:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String extract = recurseKeys(jObj, "extract");
```