# Trouble with parsing Json in android

Tags: android, json

My server-side programmer added CoCart api plugin for wp on his server. I got respose from server:

```
{
"0c6e4b403b2381e055e3afb9c9e82192": {
    "key": "0c6e4b403b2381e055e3afb9c9e82192",
    "product_id": 36187,
    "variation_id": 36188,
    "variation": {
        "attribute_pa_colour": "black-de",
        "attribute_pa_size": "m"
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "data_hash": "8efa7dad6a9c192be37892171605600f",
    "line_tax_data": {
        "subtotal": [],
        "total": []
    },
    "line_subtotal": 1250,
    "line_subtotal_tax": 0,
    "line_total": 1250,
    "line_tax": 0,
    "data": {},
    "product_name": "Женское пальто - Black"
},
"7c9c27e24ba60230327a8d915f71ae70": {
    "key": "7c9c27e24ba60230327a8d915f71ae70",
    "product_id": 36169,
    "variation_id": 36170,
    "variation": {
        "attribute_pa_colour": "green",
        "attribute_pa_size": "m"
    },
    "quantity": 2,
    "data_hash": "673b79f69d443c0e3321faa0cf145f53",
    "line_tax_data": {
        "subtotal": [],
        "total": []
    },
    "line_subtotal": 3200,
    "line_subtotal_tax": 0,
    "line_total": 3200,
    "line_tax": 0,
    "data": {},
    "product_name": "Женское пальто - Green"
}
```

}

Unfortunately, I have no any idea about what should I do with this. I use Java Android's JSONObject, but how can I get the object if keys changing every time. Exactly, keys of products. Thanks)

Comment: No it's not the answer

Comment: But what if I'll create some array, like {JsonArray array=new JsonArray()}

Comment: And put there that json

Comment: You can but you have to go through to the array position. Try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, `JSONObject` gives you a `keys()` function which returns an `Iterator` of dynamic keys (in your json), you can use that along with a hashmap for fetching and storing dynamic data -

```
try {
        JSONObject productJson = new JSONObject(productJsonString);
        Iterator keys = productJson.keys();


        HashMap<String, List<String>> dynamicList = new HashMap<>();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String currentDynamicKey = (String) keys.next();

            JSONObject currentArrayValue = productJson.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);
            ArrayList<CustomObjectWithFieldsInsideDynamicKey> currentArrayData = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < currentArrayValue.length(); i++) {
                currentArrayData.add(currentArrayValue.getString(i));
            }

            dynamicList.put(currentDynamicKey, currentArrayData);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help with this!

Answer (score 0):

There is a keys() available in JSONObject. which will return the key available in that JSONObject. Below is a given snippet to get the keys. Once you get the keys you can call getJSONObject or getJSONArray for that key.

```
String jsonString = "{\"a\":{},\"b\":{}}";
try{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(keys.next());
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately I can accept only one answer(( However, thank you))))

Answer (score 0):

This is my Java code to get keys from JSONArray.

```
private JSONArray getHeaders(JSONArray data) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        if (data.length() > 0) {
            try {
                Iterator<String> iterator = data.getJSONObject(0).keys();
                int i = 1;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterator.next();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("keyFromObject", key);
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Reference link :- [Json Object - Getting the Key and the Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826520/json-object-getting-the-key-and-the-value)